# Type as pseudo-inheritance, this method to identify elements from a Type array is good?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm new in front and react.
I want to type an element Cell, but it can be button, text, inputText, selector...
Then, i want to use the same array of data as a param in the table.
Can I use this code for this?

Type or interface, idk yet.
This type I want to been used as an param at the CustomTable

```
type CustomCell={
    align: string,
    key: number,
    inputConfig?: inputConfig,
    textConfig?: textConfig,
    buttonConfig?: buttonConfig 
}
```

I want to use this ifs to determine which type of cell I'm using

```
if(inputConfig){
    return (<CustomInput inputConfig={inputConfig}/>);
}else if(textConfig){
    return (<Typography ...../>);
}else if(buttonConfig){
    return (<CustomButton buttonConfig={buttonConfig}>);
}
```

Now I can't talk with my "seniors", and I want to work on this.
I just want to know if this method is a bad practice, or this method exist in better form.
Actually all answers are welcome